# pytorch - package importing error...i have no idea

Tags: python, pytorch

[Image of code and pytorch and my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGDNe.png)

I have no idea why this perfect baseline code is not running on my pc.
I fail to install "processes" package.
I fail to use modules of "tools".

Please help me...
The Perfect baseline is below.

https://github.com/audio-captioning/dcase-2020-baseline

Comment: try adding the top level project directory to PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. make sure that you are using the same virtual environment in Pycharm(or the IDE) in which you have installed this.

You can run `which python` to check the python interpreter. Ensure that it is same in where you have installed. Also, check with `pip list` if proper installation is there and then go for the same import statement in a python terminal.